# Grouping with hyphenate not working with i18N for weekdays

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am working on a snippet for displaying opening hours and it works fine in english language and when I change the keys of array to another language it doesn't hyphenate the letters instead it does separation by comma.

**What am I doing Wrong?**

Below is the PHP code with 2 arrays with 1 commented which is in english and which works fine. Another is an italian langugage weekdays

```
    <?php
    /*
    // english weekdays
    $openHours = array(
        'Mon' => '9am-7pm',
        'Tue' => '9am-7pm',
        'Wed' => '9am-7pm',
        'Thu' => '9am-10pm',
        'Fri' => 'closed',
        'Sat' => '9am-10pm',
        'Sun' => '9am-10pm'
    );
    */
    // italian weekdays
    $openHours = array(
        'lunedì' => '9am-7pm',
        'martedì' => '9am-7pm',
        'mercoledì' => '9am-7pm',
        'giovedì' => '9am-10pm',
        'venerdì' => 'closed',
        'sabato' => '9am-10pm',
        'domenica' => '9am-10pm'
    );

    $new_array = array();
    foreach($openHours as $key => $value)
    {
      if(in_array($value,$new_array))
      {
         $key_new = array_search($value, $new_array);//to get the key of element
         unset($new_array[$key_new]); //remove the element
         $key_new = $key_new.','.$key; //updating the key
         $new_array[$key_new] = $value; //inserting new element to the key 
      }
      else
      {
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
      }
    }

    foreach ($new_array as $days=>$time){
        $daylist = explode(',',$days);
        if ($time!='closed'){
        if (count($daylist)>2){
            $limit = count($daylist)-1;
            $first = $daylist[0];
            $last = $daylist[$limit];
            //loop will go here.
            if (date('D', strtotime('+'.$limit.' days', strtotime($first)))==$last){
                echo $first.'-'.$last.' '.$time.'<br>';
            } else {
                $sep = '';
                foreach ($daylist as $sepdays){
                    echo $sep.$sepdays;
                    $sep = ',';
                }
                echo ' '.$time.'<br>';
            }

        } else {
            echo $days.' '.$time.'<br>';
        }
        } else {
            $daylist = explode(',',$days);
            foreach ($daylist as $sepdays){
                    echo $sepdays.' '.$time.'<br>';
                }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

**RESULT**
Current Result what am getting with italian language.

```
lunedì,martedì,mercoledì 9am-7pm
venerdì closed
giovedì,sabato,domenica 9am-10pm
```

**Expected RESULT**
This is what I'm expecting.

```
lunedì-mercoledì 9am-7pm
venerdì closed
giovedì,sabato,domenica 9am-10pm
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your array's keys within [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions to do your comparisons, both functions works for English. If you need to do it on other languages you should use [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), it will be a lot more complicated process. My suggestions:

1. Use numeric representation of the days of the week (0-6) and on display, replace the number with the value for the desired language.
2. Use multidimensional arrays including the numeric day of the week and the opening hours.